# How can i make a new node title into a taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have a Drupal 7 content type that, when a new instance is created, its title becomes a new taxonomy term in a vocabulary. How can I do this?

Additionally, if the Title is changed, or the node deleted, then the corresponding Vocabulary should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://datasmith.net/blog/rules-based-taxonomy-term-creation-drupal-7) might help you sort it out with the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Otherwise you would have to create your own module and look into the [hooks mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5248234/1347661).

Comment: enzipher thanks. I will try suggested Rules approach and [Node Auto Tag](http://drupal.org/project/nat) and report back.

Answer (score 0):

**[Node Auto Term](https://www.drupal.org/project/nat)** should be the right module. https://www.drupal.org/project/nat